# Scala: getting result of PartialFunction

Tags: scala, akka

My `Akka` actor system has some tests to verify message content

```
myEventActor.expectMsgPF() {
    verifyEventPF(id)
}

def verifyEventPF(id: String): PartialFunction[Any, Any] = {
    case e : MyEvent if e.id == id => e.otherID
}
```

For example, we use this partial function to check that the id on the event is correct.
But how do I go about getting the result of the partial function e.g. if I want to achieve the following

```
myEventActor.expectMsgPF() {
    var otherID = verifyEventPF(id) // How do I achieve this?
}
```

Is this possible?

(I am aware I don't need to use a partial function here and could use `Akka TestProbe.receiveOne()` but I'd like to understand how this is possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `verfiyEventPF(id)` returns a `PartialFunction[Any, Any]`. You have to also call the returned function (giving it input, of course): `verifyEventPF(id)(event)`.

This is the same as the following:

```
val getId: PartialFunction[Any, Any] = verifyEventPF(id)
getId(event)
```

If you're concerned about the partial funciton not being defined for a particular input, you can check if the function is defined for a given value:

```
if (getId.isDefinedAt(event)) {
  getId(event)
}
```

Or you can lift the partial function into a total function that returns an `Option`:

```
val totalGetId: (Any => Option[Any]) = getId.lift
val result: Option[Any] = totalGetId(event)
```